# Restrict a controller HTTP Request by Cutomer email and password?

Tags: api, magento-1, http-request

I had a similar question before, but I want to re-structure otherwise now.

I want to make something like **http://icecat.biz/** In that site, I can access to XMLs with products datasheets, making a HTTP Request to:

http://data.icecat.biz/xml_s3/xml_server3.cgi

And sending my creedentials and the product sku. For example, using **PHP** and **Zend Framework**:

```
        $attributes = array('prod_id' => '*PRODUCT_SKU*', 'vendor' => '*PRODUCT_VENDOR_CODE*', 'lang' => 'EN', 'output' => 'productxml');

        try{
            $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
            $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
            $client->setHeaders('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
            $client->setUri('http://data.icecat.biz/xml_s3/xml_server3.cgi');
            $client->setParameterGet($attributes);
            $client->setAuth('*MyIcecataUser*', '*MyIcecatPassword*', Zend_Http_CLient::AUTH_BASIC);
            $response = $client->request();
```

Where:

- **PRODUCT_SKU** is the SKU I want to read.
- **PRODUCT_VENDOR_CODE** is the code of the vendor, for example *HP*.
- **MyIcecataUser** is my user when I registered in Icecat.
- **MyIcecatPassword** is the password of my user in Icecat.

The code return me a XML structure, with the datasheet of the product, but only when I send the valid User and Password.

So, I want to make something like that in Magento, but on the side of who delivers the information. In other words, my external customers could access to a XML with my products information, from its external systems automatically, but restricted by his email and password.

I made the XML, that is no the problem. But now, it is accessible for everyone, and I am looking for a solution to make it accessible only for customer already have a valid username and password for the site (note that the site is restricted, they can only be accessed by logging, and can not be registered on their own, we have to do it directly).

So, maybe someone say me that the better way is using the API, by SOAP or REST. But, from what I understand, if I have 5,000 customers, it means that I have to create 5,000 users API, plus the new ones to be registered. So I want to know if there is way to do something similar, but using the username and password with the customer already has, and not confuse them further with a additional user and password.

I do not know if I was clear or maybe it was too confused.